# 列挙型の基になる型を取得する

Tags: c#, .net-core

列挙型には基本となる型を指定することができますが、
列挙型の値から基本となる型を取得することは出来るでしょうか。
出来るとすれば、どのように取得すればよいでしょうか。

```
public enum SampleEnum : long
{
    Value1, Value2, Value3
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Object.GetType Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2) して [Enum.GetUnderlyingType(Type) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.enum.getunderlyingtype?view=netframework-4.7.2) や [Enum.GetTypeCode Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.enum.gettypecode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_GetTypeCode) が使えるようですね。

他参考
[Get underlying/derived type of enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5305627/9014308)